# Access to related data (e.g. renderings) in Autodesk Forge using Data Management API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

Is there any possibility to access referenced data (e.g. renderings) in Autodesk forge?
Maybe, using something like

```
GET projects/:project_id/items/:item_id/relationships/refs
```

[myhub of Autodesk360](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15MY5.png)

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be exposed at the moment. Sorry.
I made a note of this in our tracking system, that this functionality is sought after.
Unfortunately, I cannot tell at the moment when it will become available.

If you set up the references yourself - at the moment that could be an attachment - then you would be able to retrieve that relationship:
[Create an Attachment](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/create-attachment/)